# Add proxy ip into HTTP_Request?

Tags: php, http, proxy, request, http-proxy

I am using http request for scrap webpage. so i am using the following code

```
    $this->rq = new HTTP_Request();
    $this->rq->addHeader(
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ja; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090715 Firefox/3.5.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'
    );
    $this->rq->addHeader('Keep-Alive', 115);
    $this->rq->addHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    $this->rq->setURL('my url');
    $this->rq->sendRequest();
```

So now i need to send proxy ip into this request call.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `$this->rq->setProxy(<proxy hostname>, <optional proxy port>, <optional username>, <optional port> );` ?

Comment: I might be missing something, but the question was how to provide proxy details to a PHP `HTTP_Request->sendRequest()` call.
The answer tells how to provide proxy details to a PHP `HTTP_Request->sendRequest()` call. Anyway, the author of the question can correct me as needed.

Comment: ya @RomanK i already tried this $this->rq->setProxy('179.252.58.131',8080). but its not working for me...

Comment: @NathanSrivi - Can you elaborate what is not working? Do you still see the request going out direct rather than to the proxy?

Comment: i need to send form value to japan server with japan ip address. But i am from india. so only i planned to use proxy..

Comment: @NathanSrivi - I understand _why_ you need to use the proxy, but what does not work with the `setProxy` call?